# How to Show Image in a simple grid not web grid from database. Image saved in byte array format

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and I am trying to show the image in a simple grid, but the grid appears blank. The image is saved in byte array format. I am getting the other column details but not the image.

Below is the complete controller code for saving the image in byte array format and displaying from database:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Savedata(HttpPostedFileBase Image)
{
    SaveImage obj = new SaveImage();
    string result;

    if (Image != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase httpobj = Request.Files["Image"];
        string[] Imagename = httpobj.FileName.Split('.');
        obj.ImageName=Imagename[0];

        using (Stream inputStream = Request.Files[0].InputStream) //File Stream which is Uploaded  
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
            if (memoryStream == null)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            obj.ImagePic = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }  

        var path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Image.FileName) + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss") + Path.GetExtension(Image.FileName);
        result = path.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        var serversavepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/DemoImages/") + result);
        Image.SaveAs(serversavepath);                

        obj.ImageName= result;
        entity.SaveImages.Add(obj);
        entity.SaveChanges();                
    }

    //return View("Index");
    return Content("<script>alert('Data Successfully Submitted');location.href='../Home/Index';</script>"); 
}

public JsonResult BindGrid()
{            
    DataRow[] result;

    var output = (from c in entity.SaveImages.AsEnumerable()
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = c.Id,
                      ImageName = c.ImageName,
                      //ImagePic = c.ImagePic,
                      ImagePic = Convert.ToBase64String(c.ImagePic)                             

                  }).ToList();           

    var data = new { result = output };

    return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my complete View code. I am using a single view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/BindGrid")", null, function (data) { bindgrid(data); }, "Json");

        });


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function save() {

            debugger;
            $("#btnSave").click(function () {

                location.href = '@Url.Action("Savedata", "Home")';

            });
        });


        function bindgrid(data) {

            var body = "";
            $("#Grid tbody").empty();
            $.each(data.result, function (key, value) {

                body += "<tr><td> " + value.ID + "</td>" +

                "<td>" + value.ImageName + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + value.ImagePic + "</td>" +

            "<td>  <a style='cursor:pointer' onclick=Edit(" + value.Id + ");>Edit</a> <a style='cursor:pointer' onclick=Delete(" + value.Id + ");>Delete</a></td></tr>";

            });
            $("#Grid tbody").append(body);
        }

    </script>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Savedata", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {       

            <div>  
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Upload Image
                        </td>

                        <td><input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" style="width:100%" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>      

            </div>
            <br/>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="save" id="btnSave" />
            </div>
        }
        <div id="list" style="width: 997px; margin-right: 0px;">
            <table id="Grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            IMAGE NAME
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IMAGES
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            ACTION
                        </th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in entity.SaveImages)
                    {                       
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Id</td>
                            <td>@item.ImageName</td>
                            <td><img src="~/DemoImages/@item.ImagePic" width="100" height="100" /></td>    
                            @*<td><img src="string.format("data:image/png;base64 {0}",base64data)"/></td>*@                        

                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the grid to display the images with other column details.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side code seems a little bit confused. I don't know if this is the result of misunderstanding, or multiple different attempts to make it work, or what. But the thing which stands out is that you are saving the image both to the server's disk **and** to the database. I can't see a reason to do both. Normally it's more efficient to save the file directly to disk, and just write the path and filename to the database, so the file can be located later.

P.S. Also I can't understand why you sometimes used `Request.Files["Image"];` when the file is already available via the `Image` variable. And it's strange to remove the extension from the filename when storing, because then you lose information about what kind of file it is (and you aren't storing the MIME type instead either). And you also try to give two different values to `obj.ImageName` on different lines. This makes no sense.

So all you'd really need is this, I think:

```
public ActionResult Savedata(HttpPostedFileBase Image)
{
    SaveImage obj = new SaveImage();
    string result;

    if (Image != null)
    {
        obj.ImageName = Image.FileName;

        string imageFolder = "~/DemoImages/";
        var path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Image.FileName) + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss") + Path.GetExtension(Image.FileName);
        result = path.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        var serversavepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(imageFolder) + result);
        Image.SaveAs(serversavepath);                

        obj.ImageName = imageFolder + result;
        entity.SaveImages.Add(obj);
        entity.SaveChanges();                
    }

    return Content("<script>alert('Data Successfully Submitted');location.href='../Home/Index';</script>"); 
}
```

The BindGrid method will be pretty similar, just without the ImagePic field:

```
public JsonResult BindGrid()
{            
    DataRow[] result;

    var output = (from c in entity.SaveImages.AsEnumerable()
      select new
      {
        ID = c.Id,
        ImageName = c.ImageName
      }).ToList();           

    var data = new { result = output };

    return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then in the View, you would only need the following to display it (because the folder name is already in the ImageName field, so it's a ready-made relative URL):

```
<img src="@item.ImageName" width="100" height="100" />
```

Answer (score -1):

you could create `<img>` tag inside td and set base64 string to src attribute.

```
<tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in entity.SaveImages)
                    {                       
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Id</td>
                            <td>@item.ImageName</td>
                            <td><img src="'data:image/jpg;base64,' + @item.ImagePic" width="100" height="100" /></td>    
                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>
```

Comment: I am using this in view code <td><img src="~/DemoImages/@item.ImagePic" width="100" height="100" /></td>

Comment: As you said your image is in byte array. so how can you bind with relative path.check my answer

Comment: I tried this as well but still not getting the Image on Grid

Comment: I tried this code <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in entity.SaveImages)
                    {                       
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Id</td>
                            <td>@item.ImageName</td>
                            <td><img src="'data:image/jpg;base64,' + @item.ImagePic" width="100" height="100" /></td>    
                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>

Comment: I am using this code for converting image data to base 64 string ImagePic = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(c.ImagePic))

Comment: @Md.ShakirKarim use the browser's View Source feature and take a look at your final rendered HTML for your image tag, based on the code in your comment above. You'll see `data:image/jpg;base64` printed in the "src" twice, because you added it once in the String.Format operation and again the HTML. That's most likely why it isn't working. Also, hard-coding "jpg" into there is a bad idea if the user can upload png and bmp and gif etc as well. But anyway, you don't need to do any of this...[see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170802/5947043)